# How to speed up VMWare shared folders?

Tags: vmware-workstation, vmware-player, shared-folders

What is the best way to setup/optimize shared folders in VMWare for the fasted possible I/O?

I'm [not](http://kejser.org/vm-ware-shared-folders-are-really-slow/), [the](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/vagrant-up/3H49nLTgpD8), [only](https://dmitrybond.wordpress.com/2013/01/28/vmware-shared-folder-is-very-stupid-thing/), [one](http://www.midwesternmac.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/nfs-rsync-and-shared-folder) who has noticed shared folders are painfully slow. I'm using shared folders for web site testing (Drupal, WordPress) and/or compiling code (VS, gcc) across different VM environments, so I'd rather not have 5+ rsync'd NFS with the same data.

---

If SF are always going to be slow, what is the best/most performant way to share folders between host and guest for a web/compiling situation?

(Win 8 host, VM workstations of various guests (OSX, Unbuntu, etc.))

Comment: Have them on SSD.

Comment: What version of VMware Workstation (or Player) are you using?  In general, network shares are faster than shared folders.

Comment: @Ramhound Who uses HDD anymore? Lol

Comment: @jamesdlin I'd be interested in knowing why this is. (It's the last two major VM workstation releases)

Comment: Most people if they need large RAIDs or lots of storage space SSD is still several factors more expensive per GB

Comment: @Ramhound Be that is it may, SSDs are being used here. But even if they weren't, SF are slower than NFS. How to speed them up?

Comment: @Drakes Historically shared folder data is sent through the backdoor (see https://sites.google.com/site/chitchatvmback/backdoor ), which does not have high I/O throughput.  The usual recommendation is to use network shares (i.e. NFS shares, CIFS shares, ...).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you can get a drastically faster connection by using Windows file sharing (SMB), with bridged networking selected (as opposed to NAT).

This is discussed in this thread:
https://communities.vmware.com/thread/520731?start=30&tstart=0

> RusIsh Apr 27, 2018 9:29 PM (in response to swineone)
>
> Expose the VM to the base network by selecting the physical LAN adapter in the "Bridged Networking" sections in "Network Adapter" settings. Map network resource as a mapped drive in Guest OS. Try and perform some operations on the newly mapped drive.

Here's some benchmarks also on that page of the thread:

> geneg1 Jul 5, 2018 3:07 PM (in response to RusIsh)
>
> Just did a little testing on my own C++ project in Visual Studio 2013 running on VMWare Fusion 10.0.1, macOS 10.13.15, guest OS Windows 10 x64 Pro
>
> 1. Full project rebuild with source files local to the guest OS: 219 seconds
> 2. Full project rebuild with source files on host OS, connected via Windows file sharing (SMB), using bridged networking: 355 seconds
> 3. Full project rebuild with source files on host OS, connected via Windows file sharing (SMB), using NAT networking: 2257 seconds (not a typo)
> 4. Full project rebuild with source files on host OS, connected via VMWare Shared Folders (HGFS), using NAT networking: 2168 seconds
>
> So @Ruslsh is definitely on to something. Bridged networking vs. NAT made a huge difference, at least for me. Still 40% slower than keeping the source files on the guest OS though.
>
> Just for kicks I tried turning Windows Defender off on test #2 and the result was 342 seconds. A measurable but not huge savings. I'm not running any other AV software on the host or guest.

Answer (score 0):

For me disabling Anti-Virus Realtime protection on Windows 10 made a HUGE difference in HGFS speed. 5x - 6x

Comment: Null result for me when I tried this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this won't help nearly as much as switching from NAT to Bridged Networking, or using SMB, but if you're looking to squeeze any extra performance from your disks on Windows, try this:

```
; Disable "low disk space" notifications and checking for available disk space
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"NoLowDiskSpaceChecks"=dword:1

;disable 8.3 names and last access
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem]
"NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation"=dword:1
"NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate"=dword:1
```